# How can i delete items in nativescript radlistview and load new ones

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

i'm working on a ***nativescript*** project with ***radlistview***.
when i navigate to the page with the ***radlistview***, it shows the items.
when i leave the page and go back, instead of reloading new items, it still shows the previous items.

how can i achieve this please.

this is the code i use to populate the radlistview

```
fetch("https://example.com/skog/searchResults.php?search=" + searchedSkill).then((response) => response.json()).then((res) => {
       viewModel.set("items", res.items);
        viewModel.set("isBusy", false);

   }).catch((err) => {

  });
```

**i'm using nativescript core**

Comment: Depends on when / where you are loading the data, how you are handling data model. Can you share the complete or possibly a Playground sample?

Comment: @Manoj [link](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=fJrbV3&v=141) i load the data on the searchresults page with the variable stored in appSettings by the home page

Comment: Please share a minimal sample that focuses on the problem alone, its hard to debug through your whole project.

Comment: @Manoj sorry about that, i created a simplified one [link](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=4LhiUD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same view model instance every time. Move your view model creation statement to page loaded event.

**From**

```
const searchViewModel = new SearchViewModel();

exports.pageLoaded = function (args) {
    const page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = searchViewModel;
    ...
}
```

**To**

```
exports.pageLoaded = function (args) {
    const page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = new SearchViewModel();
    ...
}
```